# Schedule Job in SQL Server 2017 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which stores Finance Fiscal Period Close dates.

I wanted to run a stored procedure on those dates. How can I link the database table to pick the date and time from those tables and run the job accordingly?

These dates usually get populated at the beginning of the FY but can get update between.

Comment: Have you had a look at SQL Server Agent? If not, I suggest that be your first step. If yes, where did you get up to?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a job that runs daily with a T-SQL Script step that executes something like this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * 
        FROM FinanceFiscalPeriodCloseDates
        WHERE CloseDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE())
    EXECUTE SomeProcedure;
```

If you don't know how to create and schedule a job, then the problem might be broader.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a dynamic schedule on which a job will run.

What you can do is schedule the job to run every day, and have the first step of the stored proc be to check if today's date is in the table.   If yes, then proceed with the other steps.   If no, then don't do anything.